# Serial Numbers from a Storage Controller over SSH

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, ssh

**Background** 
I'm working on a bash script to pull serial numbers and part numbers from all the devices in a server rack, my goal is to be able to run a single script (inventory.sh) and walk away while it generates text files containing the information I need. I'm using bash for maximum compatibility, the RHEL 6.7 systems do have Perl and Python installed, however they have minimal libraries. So far I haven't had to use anything other than bash, but I'm not against calling a Perl or Python script from my bash script.

**My Problem**
I need to retrieve the Serial Numbers and Part numbers from the drives in a Dot Hill Systems AssuredSAN 3824, as well as the Serial numbers from the equipment inside. The only way I have found to get all the information I need is to connect over SSH and run the following three commands dumping the output to a local file:

- show controllers
- show frus
- show disks

**Limitations:**

- I don't have "sshpass" installed, and would prefer not to install it.
- The Controller is not capable of storing SSH keys ( no option in custom shell).
- The Controller also cannot write or transfer local files.
- The Rack does NOT have access to the Internet.
- I looked at paramiko, but while Python is installed I do not have pip.
- I also cannot use CPAN.
- For what its worth, the output comes back in XML format. (I've already written the code to parse it in bash)

Right now I think my best option would be to have a library for Python or Perl in the folder with my other scripts, and write a script to dump the commands' output to files that I can parse with my bash script. Which language is easier to just provide a library in a file? I'm looking for a library that is as small and simple as possible to use. I just need a way to get the output of those commands to XML files. Right now I am just using ssh 3 times in my script and having to enter the password each time.

Comment: To avoid keying in a password on every ssh connect you could put your local user's public ssh key (like `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into the remote user's `.ssh/autorized_keys` file. Then do e.g. `ssh remote_user@remote_host "show controllers"`. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Library recommendations are specifically off-topic here. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. And your question is quite broad anyway. Having said all that, one possible library that may help is [pyexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which will allow you to initate your ssh, run commands and get the output. Good luck!

Comment: @PerlDuck The remote system isn't running a full Linux shell, it is a custom shell written for the Controller itself. The shell doesn't give me any filesystem level access at all, so adding the keys in the remote system is unfortunately not an option. That is however, how I have been getting information from the Linux servers in the rack.

Comment: [This blog post](http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/) shows a way to _insecurely_ pipe a password to ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting the Manufacturer and asking my question. They said that the system isn't setup for connecting without a password, and their SNMP is very basic and won't provide the information I need. They said to connect to the system with FTP and use "get logs " to download an archive of the configuration and logs. Not exactly ideal as it takes 4 minutes just to run that one command but it seems to be my only option. Below is the script I wrote to retrieve the file automatically by adding the login credentials to the .netrc file. This works on RHEL 6.7:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Retrieve the logs and configuration from a Dot Hill Systems AssuredSAN 3824 automatically.
#Modify "LINE" and "HOST" to fit your configuration.
LINE='machine <IP> login manage password <password>'
HOST='<IP>'
AUTOLOGIN="/root/.netrc"
FILE='logfiles.zip'
#Check for and verify the autologin file
if [ -f $AUTOLOGIN ]; then
    printf "Found auto-login file, checking for proper entry... \r"
    READLINE=`cat $AUTOLOGIN | grep "$LINE"`
    #Append the line to the end of .netrc if file exists but not the line.
    if [ "$LINE" != "$READLINE" ]; then
        printf "Proper entry not found, creating it...                       \r"
        echo "$LINE" >> "$AUTOLOGIN"
    else
        printf "Proper entry found...                                        \r"
    fi
#Create the Autologin file if it doesn't exist
else
    printf "Auto-Login file does not exist, creating it and setting permissions...\r"
    echo "$LINE" > "$AUTOLOGIN"
    chmod 600 "$AUTOLOGIN"
fi
#Start getting the information from the controller. (This takes a VERY long time)
printf "Retrieving Storage Controller data, this will take awhile...              \r"
ftp $HOST << SCRIPT
get logs $FILE
SCRIPT
exit 0
```

This gave me a bunch of files in the zip, but all I needed was the "store_....logs" file. It was about 500,000 lines long, the first portion is the entire configuration in XML format, then the configuration in text format, followed by the logs from the system. I parsed the file and stripped off the logs at the end which cut the file down to 15,000 lines. From there I divided it into two files (config.xml and config.txt). I then pulled the XML output of the 3 commands that I needed and it to the 3 files my previously written script searches for. Now my inventory script pulls in everything it needs, albeit pretty slow due to waiting 4 minutes for the system to generate the zip file. I hope this helps someone in the future.

**Edit:**
Waiting 4 minutes for the system to compile was taking too long. So I ended up using paramiko and python scripts to dump output from the commands to files that my other code can parse. It accepts the IP of the Controller as a parameter. Here is the script for those interested. Thank you again for all the help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Saves output of "show disks" from the storage Controller to an XML file.

import paramiko
import sys
import re
import xmltodict

IP = sys.argv[1]
USERNAME = "manage"
PASSWORD = "password"
FILENAME = "./logfiles/disks.xml"

cmd = "show disks"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
        client.connect(IP,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(1)

data = ""
for line in stdout:
    if re.search('#', line):
        pass
    else:
        data += line
client.close()

f = open(FILENAME, 'w+')
f.write(data)
f.close()

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SNMP. There is a reasonable chance that you can use SNMP tools to remotely extract the information you need. The manufacturer should be able to provide you with the MIBs.

Comment: I used "snmpwalk" and then searched the output for known values such as Serial numbers pulled from the XML files I had dumped, and nothing came up. Unfortunately the system has a very limited number of SNMP objects. 

I decided to give sshpass a try, and it wouldn't even authenticate. I tested on a plain Linux server, and it worked just fine, so something is different about this Storage Controller's CLI.

Comment: A quick search revealed [this document](https://crc.dothill.com/access/content/group/CRC/Documentation/AssuredSAN%20Ultra48%20Series/DH_RAIDar_UG_83-00006696-11-01-A.pdf) for an AssuredSAN 4004. Look at page 130 onwards. It describes the FA MIB 2.2 that should also apply to your equipment. You wont reach this MIB with a standard snpwalkm you will have to know its location to query it.